# PHP: Displaying an image from a web service

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm using an external web service that will return an image URL which i will display in my website, For example :

```
$url = get_from_web_service();
echo '<img url="'.$url.'" />';
```

everything is working fine except if i have 100 images to show then calling the web service become time & resources consuming.

```
//the problem
foreach($items as $item) {
   $url = get_from_web_service($item);
   echo '<img url="'.$url.'" />';
}
```

So now i'm considering two options:

```
//Option1: Using php get_file_contents():
foreach($items as $item)
{
   echo '<img url="url_to_my_website/get_image.php?id='.$item->id.'" />'
}

get_image.php :

$url = get_from_web_service($id);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents($url);


//Option2: Using ajax:

echo '<img scr="dummy_image_or_website_logo" data-id="123" />';

//ajax call to the web service to get the id=123 and get the url then add the src attribute to that image.
```

**THOUGHTS**

1. First option seems more straight forward, but my server might be
   overloaded and involved in every single image request.
2. Second option it's all done by browser & web service so my server is not involved at all. but for each image i'm making 2 calls 1 ajax call to get the image URL and another one one to get the image. so loading time might be vary and ajax calls might fail for large number of calls.

**Information**

1. Around 50 Images will be displayed in that page.
2. This service will be used by around a 100 user at a given time.
3. I have no control over the web service so i can't change its functionality and it doesn't accept more than 1 image ID for each call.

**My Questions**

1. Any better option i should consider?
2. If not, which option should I follow? and most important why i should follow that one?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried "lazy load" extension? [Example](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Comment: Ya i already have it installed but do you think a 100 ajax call + a 100 image call is a good idea ? @Drazzi

Comment: @ra_htial: Nah, not the best idea ever... not at all. Especially since you're not setting any cache-control headers... try keeping the images in a DB, cache them as if your life depended on it, and even then... clients will request those 100 imgs via AJAX calls? why? that's just painful for both client and server

Comment: @ra_htial The user didn't browse your whole page, I have explain it at my answer bellow, it at least can reduce it less than 100.

Comment: @ra_htial I've updated my answer for your bounty. Please read through it and see if it helps. If you have any questions, feel free to leave a comment on it and I'll get back to it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Method 1: Rendering in PHP

**Pros:**

- Allows for custom headers that're independent of any server software. If you're using something that's not generally cached (like a PHP file with a query string) or are adding this to a package that needs header functionality regardless of server software, this is a very good idea.
- If you know how to use [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), you can easily resize, crop, compress, index, etc. your images to reduce the image file size (sometimes drastically) and make the page load significantly faster.
- If width and height are passed as variables to the PHP file, the dimensions can be set dynamically:

  ```
   <div id="gallery-images">
       <noscript>
           <!-- So that the thumbnail is small for old mobile devices //-->
           <img src="get-image.php?id=123&h=200&w=200" />
       </noscript>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       /* Something to create an image element inside of the div.
        * In theory, the browser height and width can be pulled dynamically
        * on page load, which is useful for ensuring that images are no larger
        * than they need to be. Having a function to load the full image
        * if the borwser becomes bigger isn't a bad idea though.
        */
   </script>
  ```

This would be incredibly considerate of mobile users on a page that has an image gallery. This is also very considerate of users with limited bandwidth (like almost everyone in Alaska. I say this from personal experience).

- Allows you to easily clear the EXIF data of images if they're uploaded by users on the website. This is important for user privacy as well as [making sure there aren't any malicious scripts living in your JPGs](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/).
- Gives potential to dynamically create a large [image sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) and drastically reduce your HTTP requests if they're causing latency. It'd be a lot of work so this isn't a very strong pro, but it's still something you can do using this method that you can't do using the second method.

**Cons**:

- Depending on the number and size of images, this could put a lot of strain on your server. When used with browser-caching, the dynamic images are being pulled from cache instead of being re-generated, however it's still very easy for a bot to be served the dynamic image a number of times.
- It requires knowledge of HTTP headers, basic image manipulation skills, and an understanding of how to use image manipulation libraries in PHP to be effective.

## Method 2: AJAX

**Pros:**

- The page would finish loading before any of the images. This is important if your content absolutely needs to load as fast as possible, and the images aren't very important.
- Is far more simple, easy and significantly faster to implement than any kind of dynamic PHP solution.
- It spaces out the HTTP requests, so the initial content loads faster (since the HTTP requests can be sent based on browser action instead of just page load).

**Cons:**

- It doesn't decrease the number of HTTP requests, it simply spaces them out. Also note that there will be at least one additional external JS file in addition to all of these images.
- Displays nothing if the end device (such as older mobile devices) does not support JavaScript. The only way you could fix this is to have all of the images load normally between some `<noscript>` tags, which would require PHP to generate twice as much HTML.
- Would require you to add `loading.gif` (and another HTTP request) or `Please wait while these images load` text to your page. I personally find this annoying as a website user because I want to see everything when the page is "done loading".

## Conclusion:

If you have the background knowledge or time to learn how to effectively use Method 1, it gives far more potential because it allows for manipulation of the images and HTTP requests sent by your page after it loads.

Conversely, if you're looking for a simple method to space out your HTTP Requests or want to make your content load faster by making your extra images load later, Method 2 is your answer.

Looking back at methods 1 and 2, it looks like using both methods together could be the best answer. Having two of your cached and compressed images load with the page (one is visible, the other is a buffer so that the user doesn't have to wait every time they click "next"), and having the rest load one-by-one as the user sees fit.

**In your specific situation, I think that Method 2 would be the most effective if your images can be displayed in a "slideshow" fashion.** If all of the images need to be loaded at once, try compressing them and applying browser-caching with method 1. If too many image requests on page load is destroying your speed, try image spriting.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, you are contacting the webservice 100 times. You should change it so it contacts the webservice only **once** and retrieves an array of all the 100 images, instead of each image separately.

You can then loop over this array, which will be very fast as no further webtransactions are needed.

Comment: This assumes the service includes such a method or else the interface can be changed...

Answer (score 2):

If the images you are fetching from the webservice are not dynamic in  nature i.e. do not get changed/modified frequently, I would suggest to setup a scheduled process/cron job on your server which gets the images from the webservice and stores locally (in your server itself), so you can display images on the webpage from your server only and avoid third party server round trip every time webpage is served to the end users.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the 2 option cannot resolve your problem, may be make it worse.

For option 1:

The process where cost most time is "`get_from_web_service($item)`", and the code is only made it be executed by another script( if the file "`get_image.php`" is executed at the same server).

For option 2:

It only make the "get-image-resource-request" being trigger by browser, but your server has also need to process the "`get_from_web_service($item)`".

One thing must be clear is that the problem is about the performance of get_from_web_service, the most straight proposal is to make it have a better performance. On the other hand, we can make it reduce the number of concurrent connections. I haven't thought this through, only have 2 suggestion:

1. **Asynchronous**: The user didn't browse your whole page, they only notice the page at the top. If your mentioned images does not all displayed at the top, you can use jquery.lazyload extension, it can make the image resource at invisible region do not request the server until they are visible.
2. **CSS Sprites** : An image sprite is a collection of images put into a single image. If images on your page does not change frequency, you can write some code to merge them daily.
3. **Cache Image** : You can cache your image at your server, or another server (better). And do some key->value works: key is about the $item, value is the resource directory(url).

I am not a native english speaker, hope I made it clear and helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

im not an expert, but im thinking everytime you echo, it takes time. getting 100 images shouldnt be a problem (solely)

Also. maybe `get_from_web_service($item);` should be able to take an array?

```
$counter = 1;
$urls = array();
foreach($items as $item)
{
   $urls[$counter] = get_from_web_service($item);
   $counter++;
}
// and then you can echo the information?
foreach($urls as $url)
{
   //echo each or use a function to better do it
    //echo '<img url="url_to_my_website/get_image?id='.$url->id.'" />'

}

get_image.php :

$url = get_from_web_service($item);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

at the end, it would be mighty nice if you can just call

```
get_from_web_service($itemArray); //intake the array and return images
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 3:
cache the requests to the web service

Answer (score 0):

Option one is the best option. I would also want to make sure that the images are cached on the server, so that multiple round trips are not required from the original web server for the same image.

If your interested, this is the core of the code that I use for caching images etc (note, that a few things, like reserving the same content back to the client etc is missing):

```
<?php
function error404() {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "Page not found.";
    exit;
}

function hexString($md5, $hashLevels=3) {
    $hexString = substr($md5, 0, $hashLevels );
    $folder = "";

    while (strlen($hexString) > 0) {
        $folder =  "$hexString/$folder";
        $hexString = substr($hexString, 0, -1);
    }

    if (!file_exists('cache/' . $folder))
        mkdir('cache/' . $folder, 0777, true);

    return 'cache/' . $folder . $md5;
}

if (!isset($_GET['img']))
    error404();

getFile($_GET['img']);

function getFile($url) {
    // true to enable caching, false to delete cache if already cached
    $cache = true;

    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_MAXCONNECTS => 15,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 360,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Image Download'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $defaults);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['img']);

    $key  = hexString(sha1($url));
    if ($cache && file_exists($key)) {
        return file_get_contents($key);
    } elseif (!$cache && file_exists($key)) {
        unlink($key);
    }

    $data = curl_exec($this->_ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($this->_ch);

    if ($cache === true && $info['http_code'] == 200 && strlen($data) > 20)
        file_put_contents($key, $data);
    elseif ($info['http_code'] != 200)
        error404();

    return $data;
}

$content = getURL($_GET['img']);
if ($content !== null or $content !== false) {
    // Success!
    header("Content-Type: image");
    echo $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the two options will resolve server resources usage issue. Out of the two, though, I would recommend option 1. The second one will delay page loading, causing website speed to slow down, and reducing your SEO ratings.

Best option for you would be something like:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo '<img url="url_to_my_website/get_image.php?id='.$item->id.'" />'
}
```

Then where the magic happens is **get_image.php**:

```
if(file_exists('/path_to_local_storage/image_'.$id.'.png')) {
    $url = '/path_to_images_webfolder/image_'.$id.'.png';
    $img = file_get_contents($url);
} else {
    $url = get_from_web_service($id);
    $img = file_get_contents($url);
    $imgname = end(explode('/', $url));
    file_put_contents($imgname, $img);
}

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $img;
```

This was you will only run the request to web service once per image, and then store it on your local space. Next time the image is requested - you will serve it form your local space, skipping request to web service.

Of course, considering image IDs to be unique and persistent.

Probably not the best solution, but should work pretty well for you.

Answer (score 0):

As we see that above you're including an URL to the web service provided image right in the `<img>` tag `src` attribute, one can safely assume that these URLs are not secret or confidential.

Knowing that above, the following snippet from the `get_image.php` will work with the least overhead possible:

```
$url = get_from_web_service($id);
header("Location: $url");
```

If you're getting a lot of subsequent requests to the same `id` from a given client, you can somewhat lessen number of requests by exploiting browser's internal cache.

```
header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=$seconds");
header("Expires: ".gmdate('r', time()+$seconds));
```

Else resort to server-side caching by means of Memcached, database, or plain files like so:

```
is_dir('cache') or mkdir('cache');
$cachedDataFile = "cache/$id";
$cacheExpiryDelay = 3600; // an hour

if (is_file($cachedDataFile) && filesize($cachedDataFile) 
     && filemtime($cachedDataFile) + $cacheExpiryDelay > time()) {
    $url = file_get_contents($cachedDataFile);
} else {
    $url = get_from_web_service($id);
    file_put_contents($cachedDataFile, $url,  LOCK_EX);
}

header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=$cacheExpiryDelay");
header("Expires: ".gmdate('r', time() + $cacheExpiryDelay));
header("Location: $url");
```